# Deserializing xml returns zero elements

Tags: c#, xml

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<orders>
  <order>
    <customer_id>5675757</customer_id>
    <order_code>6456</order_code>
    <products>
      <product>
        <product_item_code>577868</product_item_code>
        <product_item_amount>22</product_item_amount>
      </product>
    </products>
  </order>
</orders>
```

And this is my class:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "orders")]
public class Orders
{
    public List<OrderModel> OrdersList { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "order")]
public class OrderModel
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "customer_id")]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "order_code")]
    public string OrderCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "products")]
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "product")]
public class Product
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "product_item_code")]
    public string product_item_code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "product_item_amount")]
    public string product_item_amount { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my code:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Orders));
    var orders = (Orders)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
}
```

But it returns 0 elements. I know I am missing something obvious but I don't know what.

Comment: What's useful in such cases is trying to *serialize* some objects with this setup, and comparing the output to your expected input. If you try this, you should see the problem is with the `OrdersList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you class `Orders` and `OrderModel`:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "orders")]
public class Orders
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "order")]
    public List<OrderModel> OrdersList { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "order")]
public class OrderModel
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "customer_id")]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "order_code")]
    public string OrderCode { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "products")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "product")]
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}
```

Then it should work

Answer (score 0):

Modify your classes as below and it will work.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "orders")]
public class Orders
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "order")]
    public List<OrderModel> OrdersList { get; set; }
}

public class OrderModel
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "customer_id")]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "order_code")]
    public string OrderCode { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "products")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "product")]
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "product_item_code")]
    public string product_item_code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "product_item_amount")]
    public string product_item_amount { get; set; }
}
```